# How do I disable these tailwind injected style sheets?

Tags: tailwind-css

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how I wound up with these styles automatically injected into all of my VS Code run code. When I run things directly on the other hand (i.e. directly opening an HTML doc from my Finder) none of this is injected.

Where might this be coming from, and how do I "turn it off"?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you at least 3 options

First, separate this part that you will not apply to another file, and only import it whenever you need it

Second, add comments `/* This is a comment in CSS */`  in any line that you want to disable.

Third, rewrite it with a brand new class, in bottom of your styling codes. example, `*, ::before, :: after {margin: 0px}` will update the margin setting